# A non-trivial Finite field map.

Tags: finite-fields

Is there a map $\sigma$ such that at some $\tau\in\Bbb F_p^\times\backslash\{1\}$ we have at every $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb F_p$ $$\sigma(\alpha+\tau\cdot\beta)=\alpha-\tau\cdot\beta$$ holding true?

Comment: To be clear, $\sigma$ is supposed to be a map $\mathbb{F}_p\to\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes everyobject here is in $\Bbb F_p$ (if it exists we can generalize to $\Bbb F_{p^i}$ easily I would guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $\beta=0$ gives $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.  Setting $\alpha=0$ gives $\sigma(\tau\beta)=-\tau\beta$ so letting $\gamma=\tau\beta$, $\sigma(\gamma)=-\gamma$ for all $\gamma$ ($\gamma$ can be anything since $\tau\neq 0$).  So this is only possible for $p=2$, but then $\mathbb{F}_p^\times\setminus\{1\}$ is empty so it is trivially impossible.

Comment: what about if $\tau$ alone is in $\Bbb F_p^2$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb F_p$?

Comment: What does $\tau\cdot \beta$ mean then?

Comment: $\beta\in\Bbb F_p\subseteq\Bbb F_{p^2}$ and so it should be defined.

Comment: Oh, you meant $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.

Comment: yes correct it is.

Comment: Then such a map $\sigma$ trivially exists for any $\tau\not\in\mathbb{F}_p$: just define $\sigma(\alpha+\tau\beta)=\alpha-\tau\beta$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}_p$, and define $\sigma$ arbitrarily elsewhere.  This is well defined since $1$ and $\tau$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: I only get to modify $\alpha+\tau\cdot\beta$ in a blak box manner and I do not know $\alpha$ and $\beta$ individually (or equivalently $\alpha+\tau\cdot\beta$) and that is why I want an expicit map that operates on black box manner.

Comment: @Turbo: If we are allowed to pick $\tau\in\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$, then such mappings do exist as Eric (+1) explained. But when $1,\tau$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{F}_p$, the value of $z=\alpha+\beta\tau$ does determine both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ uniquely. So I don't know about the black box... Anyway, if $n$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$, then you can use $\tau=\sqrt{n}\in\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$. In that case the Frobenius mapping $\sigma(z)=z^p$ is even an automorphism of fields, and does behave like $\sigma(\alpha+\tau\beta)=\alpha-\tau\beta$.